# Apache 501 random Yii

Tags: php, apache, yii

My server is `apache`, `php`, `Yii framework`, some POST request get **501 status** randomly, I see no log in php log or in apache log. If someone has solved this type error, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in one of my applications in the backend and it is related with CSRF token. I solved it by copying CSRF token from frontend and used it in the backend. You can give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, it is my company's network firewall, which rejects some POST requests which are suspected as attack request.
The solution : add my Api to the whitelist of my company's network firewall